# get_category_link() is returning nothing

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I am using the get_categories() function to manually create myself a nav menu.  I have a custom taxonomy I'm using called Category and I'm trying to return the link for it for my  tags in the menu using the get_category_link() function.

```
foreach ($categories as $category) {
            if ($category->parent == 0) {   //Check to see it is a parent
                $output .= '<li>';
                $output .= '<a href="' . get_category_link($category->cat_ID) . '">' . $category->name . '</a>';  //display parent taxonomy category

             }
      }
```

But it always returns `<a href="">`.  I can echo out the  `$category->cat_ID` successfully so I know it is passing the ID into the function but I don't know why it's returning blank.

Am I missing something? Is it because these are custom taxonomies?  They have slugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like this for custom taxonomies:

```
$tax = 'cars';
  $cats = get_terms( $tax, '' );
  if ($cats) {
    foreach($cats as $cat) {
       $output .= "<li>";
$output .= '<a href="' . esc_attr(get_term_link($cat, $tax)) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $cat->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $cat->name.'</a>';
$output .= "</li>";
    }
  }
```

Although you can easily add to the top of the script to get an array of all taxonomies to feed in if you wanted.

Comment: What is the difference between get_terms and get_categories ?  I feel like I might have to rewrite my entire script to use get_terms instead of get_categories. Would this be the case?  Thank you!

Comment: Ahh ok you answered my question.  I need to use get_terms for custom taxonomies.  Thank you very much!